# LESS Bundling failing when deployed to IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, less, bundling-and-minification

I'm trying to use the System.Web.Optimisation.Less library to bundle a set of Less files. Everything works when I run it in visual studio, including minification, but then fails when I deploy to IIS. When I deploy the rendered link is missing a value

```
<link href="/Bundles/Style?v=" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

and if I navigate to that location the page is empty.

I've tested with a Less file which is a single CSS statement, and that still fails, so it's not a problem with the Less files themselves. The relevant parts of Web Config are

```
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
    <section name="dotless" type="dotless.Core.configuration.DotlessConfigurationSectionHandler, dotless.Core" />
    ...
    <httpHandlers>
          <add path="*.less" verb="GET" type="dotless.Core.LessCssHttpHandler, dotless.Core" />
        </httpHandlers>
    ...
    <system.webServer>
          <staticContent>
              <mimeMap fileExtension=".less" mimeType="text/css" />
          </staticContent>
    <handlers>
          <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
          <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
          <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
          <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
          <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
          <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
          <add name="dotless" path="*.less" verb="GET" type="dotless.Core.LessCssHttpHandler,dotless.Core" resourceType="File" preCondition="" />

</handlers>
        ...
    <dotless minifyCss="false" cache="true" web="false" />
```

I've used Less bundling with applications deployed to the same IIS server before, and they have worked fine, and as far as I can tell have the same configuration.

I'm using version 1.3.2 of the System.Web.Optimisation.Less library.

CSS and Script bundling is working fine.

The code in BundleConfig.cs is

```
var lessBundle = new LessBundle("~/Less/Bootstrap").Include(
                "~/Content/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less");

            bundles.Add(lessBundle);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Got it! Build Action on the Less files was set to "None"

Comment: and it should be what?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, it should be set to Content